# Authenticate Mac OS X Mountain Lion against EL6 OpenLDAP only succeeds for ssh

Tags: centos, authentication, osx-mountain-lion, openldap

I'm having an issue with mountain lion authenticating against a CentOS 6 openldap/krbkdc server. I can ssh into the macs in question and I am issued a ticket and all autofs mounts (like the homedir) function as expected. If I try the graphical login it spins and never logs in.

How can I diagnose this? I've checked system.log and opendirectoryd.log and I'm not really seeing anything that jumps out at me. I'm running in debug mode using 'odutil set log debug'.

I've set the denied sasl methods to GSSAPI as that's what my server presents. I actually have simple starttls bind working in apache directory studio while i debug but haven't a clue how to get that working on the mac side if it's poss.

All the /etc/pam.d/ files have had their pam_krb.so entries adjusted.

The weird thing is I am able to login as a local user, admin or otherwise, and I'm able to ssh in and get my complete environment.